# Oracle metadata to store column titles/labels

Tags: java, html, oracle, forms, metadata

Does Oracle have a column metadata for storing its printable friendly label?
Say I have a column named `prodDesc.` I would like to be able to pull a column label such as `"Product Description"` for use in end reports & web pages. I plan to utilize the column size meta data as well so that when I generate an html form I can dynamically set the `size` and `maxlength` parameters for the input textbox.

I realize I can use the `AS` keyword, but then I need to update this in every sql statement but I'd rather maintain column labels in one location.

A work around thought was to duplicate every table naming each with an appended _label and then each would have just one row to store column labels.  But this seems excessive.

```
tblProduct
tblProduct_label  <--- same structure as tblProduct but the values
```

BTW, This is for a java web application with an oracle backend.

**EDIT:**
this is an example xml file I am already maintaining for all my db tables...

```
<schema>
  <tableName>xtblPersonnel</tableName>
  <tableTitle>Personnel</tableTitle>
  <tableConstraints></tableConstraints>

  <column>
        <name>PID</name> 
        <type>VARCHAR2</type> 
        <size>9</size> 
        <label>Badge ID</label>
  </column> 

  <column>
        <name>PCLASS</name> 
        <type>VARCHAR2</type> 
        <size>329</size> 
        <label>Classification</label>
  </column>
<schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a UI issue, it's usually handled in the presentation layer by keeping maps of column name/label pairs (usually one map per language).  You pass the column name (or a key composed of table name+column name, if necessary) in to the map and get the label out.  If you want to keep them in the database, you can create a table with columns for the table name, column name, language ID and label, then create your maps on startup or lazily initialize them as needed.

Comment: I made an edit to my post.  I use the xml file for other things and was hoping to push the label into the db when creating the table.  I will investigate using a hashmap from my servlet to the view/UI.

Comment: OK so in my jsp I have: <% java.util.HashMap lbl = (HashMap) request.getAttribute("labels"); %> Then where I want a label: <%= ((HashMap)lbl.get("shop_order")).get("label") %>   Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: <c:out value="${hshFields.SHOP_ORDER.label}" /> much better (I can only use JSTL.  EL is not available becauuse i am stuck in jsp 1.2

Answer (score 3):

You could use the information in user_col_comments and user_tab_comments, which is stored as a result of issuing "COMMENT ON COLUMN..." or "COMMENT ON TABLE..." SQL.